# Set a background if item has an item with specific class with css

Tags: css

I want to set a background to parent element if it has an item with 'open' class item with css. Main goal is add a background color the parent element.

For example:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <span class='title'>title</span>
    <span class='arrow open'>I should have a blue background!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: A parents style can't be based on its children in CSS (excluding a few very specific situations, but they aren't relevant here)

Comment: The easiest way would be to add the `open` class to the parent so you just have you use `.parent.open{}`. Also, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)